# how to install gruff, rmagic gem on ubuntu system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, gruff

After installing gruff gem in ubuntu

while running some code I get the below error

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- RMagick (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:2
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff.rb:25
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff.rb:5:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff.rb:5
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from tremp.rb:5
```

I think this error might be because of dependcy of rmagic gem..
but while install rgamic gem

I get the below error..

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Can anybody guide me that how can I install gruff, rmagic gem on ubuntu system?

Answer (score 4):

For ruby 1.8.7...

```
$ sudo apt-get install librmagick-ruby libmagickcore-dev
$ sudo gem install rmagick
$ sudo gem install gruff
```

And it worked for me.

EDIT --
For ruby 1.9.2...

```
$ sudo apt-get install librmagick-ruby libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev 
$ sudo gem install rmagick
$ sudo gem install gruff
```

Note, in both versions, I'm not 100% sure if "libmagickcore-dev" is required or not, but I installed it earlier in trying to solve this issue, so I figured I should mention it.